# Angular 5 export html to image

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Excuse me how I can export html to an image in angular 5.

some bookstore or something?

Is there any way to do that with angular 5?

Comment: please add in more description on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add url links to images dynamically, here is the code.
You can change the input text event to that HTML link which you want to store.
HTML for module HTML:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<div>
        <input type="text" (input)="onInputEvent($event)">
</div>
<div>
    <a [href]='url'>
        <img 
        src="smiley.gif" 
        alt="HTML tutorial" 
        style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0;">
      </a>
</div>
```

module typeScript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'MY TEST';
  url:string ;
  onInputEvent(event:Event){
    this.url=(<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
  }
}
```